# Bootstrap 3 - Two Column Layout - Get rid of placeholder

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form using bootstrap 3 that looks like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbbof.png)

I can get it to look pretty similar, but the only problem I have is that my last horizontal rule in the ETO section goes the entire way across. Is there any way I can make this only go across half of the page? I tried putting it in different col sizes inside that but I couldn't get it to work. Here's my html. Thanks ahead of time!

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <label style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">JOHNSON Summary</label>
    </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Status </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <select class="form-control" id="empStatus">
                <option value="" disabled>Choose Type....</option>
                <option value="Current">Current</option>
                <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Anniversary </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empAnniversary"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Start Date </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="date" id="empStartDate"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Adjusted Start </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="date" id="empAdjustedStart"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> STD/LTD </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empSTDLTD"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Uncharged </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empUncharged"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <h4>PTO</h4>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-2"> Base </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBase" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#43; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Carryover </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoCarryover" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Borrowed </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBorrowed" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Requests </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoRequests" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Available </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoAvailable" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <h4>ETO</h4>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-2"> Earned </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoEarned" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-1"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-2"> Requests </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoRequested" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-1"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-2"> Available </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoAvailable" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using only col-xs-format? is mobile? The div used here it´s too big to see this css effect, and style link isn't included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED.**
I think you need to use Bootstrap's [horizontal form as described in official docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal). It seems you are using horizontal form structure, but you've forgotten to add `.form-horizontal` class to your `form` element or to `.form-group`.

Comment: that's possible, I'm new to using Bootstrap. But, how would that fix the problem where I want to have empty space where my placeholders are?

Comment: You mean all your placeholders(left side) must have the same width including empty space?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out after looking more into Bootstrap and using horizontal forms, thanks for that insight! I just have a problem with my last horizontal rule now with it going the entire way across the screen instead of only half. I attempted to put it into different col widths but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle to let me see your issue?

Comment: No, I want everything in the requests row (under ETO) to line up with the rest of the form. I think I actually just got it though, thanks!